# How can I get a tag-based UITextField?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How can I bring this tagging effect in an iOS `UITextField`?

[image: refer here]

I have a group of `NSStrings` and I would like to display them as given in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [JSTokenField](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jstokenfield) control.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a pretty versatile class that should do what you need. You can find it here: [RoleModel/RMSTokenView](https://github.com/RoleModel/RMSTokenView).